# What other versions of AVRstudi other then v4.19 can i use for programming

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, mingw, avr

i get this massage when i try to compile
gcc plug-in: No AVR Toolchain installation found. The AVR GCC plug-in can still be used if you set up your own build tools.
Which version of AVRstudio is working?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a good idea to say what piece of software is giving you an error message when you post questions here.  I am guessing that you are using AVR Studio 4.19 and *that* is the piece of software that is giving you that error message about the toolchain not being found.

AVR Studio 4 is designed to use the AVR GCC toolchain provided by WinAVR, so if you install WinAVR you can probably get around that message.  But I would **not** recommend using either of these pieces of software because they are extremely old and do not support the latest AVRs.

The current IDE from the company that makes AVRs is called [Microchip Studio for AVR® and SAM Devices](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/microchip-studio-for-avr-and-sam-devices).  You can download it for free and it has an updated AVR GCC toolchain that comes with it.